# SharePoint 2013 Workflow showing correct date but 0:00:00 time

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I create an approve button in a form that shows at what date the item was approved, however I am getting the correct date but the time is always 0:00:00
[image]

This is a screen of the workflow:

[image]

Comment: Is your field is datetime? as i can see it's getting different zones for time than default date time

Comment: Yeah it's a dateTime field I created in infopath 2013

Comment: Unfortunately Sharepoint designer's "Today" function only captures the date but not the time. I would suggest creating a variable that is set to the time when the Workflow is started. And then using that variable to set your field. Of course it won't be perfectly accurate but it is close enough.

Comment: You can create a field from SharePoint list & update using same variable. if it wont work than you can use the Modified value in the filed as item is going to be updated after the workflow.

Comment: Okay, will try both things and will let you know

Comment: Have you tried it? is that works for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give you 2 easy options:

1. Set **SecurityManagerApprovalTime** to the **Workflow Context: Date and Time Started** variable. This is the date and time when the workflow started which should work if the workflow starts when the security manager approves/rejects.
2. Assuming the workflow is started on SharePoint list items and the approval action is modifying the items, then you can use the **Modified** field of the items to get the date and time.

---

If none of these work for your scenario, in order to help please provide more details about how the security manager approves and who and when starts the workflow.

Comment: Suggested you the same but in comments...:)